# How can I reconnect to a remoteapp session?

Tags: remoteapp

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with some RemoteApp programs exposed to my users. When a user reconnects to a disconnected RemoteApp session the program he used before is launched once again, so there are 2 windows (instances) of the same program displaying - the old disconnected one & the newly launched.

Is it possible to reconnect to the session without launching the remote application again?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when we had a batch file launching the application, or a helper app that launched an app but then closed. in these cases, remote app has no way to know if the app is still running because the process it originally launched (which then launched another process) had closed. And since a single remoteapp session can have multiple apps running in it, it's not safe for remote app to assume that joining a disconnected session means that the requested app should not launched because it might be a different app that started the session.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a few months old, but I got here by having the same question. After reading over the above answer by longneck, I have an idea. It's just a theory, mind you, and one I haven't had opportunity to test yet, but I'm going to do so in the near future.
The idea is that instead of pointing your RemoteApp to the application itself, you point it to a script that checks to see if the process is running under the current user and, if not, then it runs the program.
I'll have to do some additional research to determine if batch will work or if VBS will be better, and I can't guarantee that any apps or even RDS will like it very much. It'll probably throw security warnings right and left... But it's something to think about.